# Mirror Image distorted after a distance

Tags: glass, mirror

I bought a mirror 9ft *4ft and image is alright till 10 ft away from the mirror after that it's distorting the image and thickening it.How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Because the surface you affixed it to is not flat

A mirror that large can't rely on its own stiffness to stay straight.  It is relying on the underlying surface.  Glass can bend a little bit.  Your surface is bending, so the mirror is bending, so you have a funhouse mirror.